# Alternative methods to solving system of equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

> Let $$ \begin{cases} \sqrt{x} = y -1 \\ \sqrt{y} = 11 - x\end{cases}$$
> Solve $x$ and $y$ in real numbers.

After a long calculation, I get to this equation: $(y−4)(y^3−16y−25)=0$. I found $x = 9$ and $y = 4$ are the only answers. What's the other methods for solving that maybe using derivation or inequalities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite like this:

$$\underbrace {\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+1}}_{f(x)} = \underbrace {11-x}_{g(x)}$$

Since $f$ is increasing and $g$ is decreasing this equation has at most one solution. After some ''playing'' with numbers in $[0,11]$ we guess that $x=9$ is a solution and thus unique.

Comment: Wow nice bounding!!!! +1

Comment: What if the inner sqrt is negative?

Comment: @ChristianF Very nice , thanks !

Comment: Then it becomes $\underbrace {\sqrt{-\sqrt{x}+1}}_{f(x)} = \underbrace {11-x}_{g(x)}$

Comment: @martycohen Take a better look.

Answer (score 0):

$$y\ge1,\quad x\le 11.\tag1$$

$$
\begin{cases}
(y-1)^2 = x\\
(11-x)^2 = y
\end{cases}\rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(y-1)^2 - 9  = x-9\\
(x-11)^2 - 4 = y-4
\end{cases}\rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(y-4)(y+2) = x - 9\\
y-4 = (x-9)(x-13).
\end{cases}
$$
$y=-2$ do not lead to the solution.

$x=13$ do not lead to solution.

So
$$
\begin{cases}
(y+2)(x-9)(x-13) = x-9\\
(y-4)(y+2)(x-13) = y-4
\end{cases}\rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(x-9)((y+2)(x-13) -1 ) = 0\\
(y-4)((y+2)(x-13) - 1) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Taking in account $(1),$
$$(y+2)(x-13) - 1 < 0,$$
so
$$(x,y) = (9,4).$$